# Problems with extracting  file summary information

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

I apologize for my English, it's not good, but I hope you will understand my question. I have problem with usage of WinAPI function `StgOpenStorageEx`. I need to get file's summary information. I found some solutions, but in all of them I need to use `StgOpenStorageEx`. Because it is not in standard modules, I declared it myself as exported from ole32.dll like this

```
function StgOpenStorageEx (
  const pwcsName : POleStr;  //Pointer to the path of the
                             //file containing storage object
  grfMode : LongInt;         //Specifies the access mode for the object
  stgfmt : DWORD;            //Specifies the storage file format
  grfAttrs : DWORD;          //Reserved; must be zero
  pStgOptions : Pointer;     //Address of STGOPTIONS pointer
  reserved2 : Pointer;       //Reserved; must be zero
  riid : PGUID;              //Specifies the GUID of the interface pointer 
  out stgOpen :              //Address of an interface pointer
  IStorage ) : HResult; stdcall; external 'ole32.dll';
```

Next I need to use this function like this

```
    var
        res, open: hresult;
        stg: IStorage;
        PropSetStg: IPropertySetStorage;
        PropStg: IPropertyStorage;
        FileName: string;

    const
        IID_IPropertySetStorage : TGUID =     '{0000013A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
        FmtID_SummaryInformation: TGUID =     '{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}';

    function StgOpenStorageEx (
     const pwcsName : POleStr;  //Pointer to the path of the
                                //file containing storage object
     grfMode : LongInt;         //Specifies the access mode for the object
     stgfmt : DWORD;            //Specifies the storage file format
     grfAttrs : DWORD;          //Reserved; must be zero
     pStgOptions : Pointer;     //Address of STGOPTIONS pointer
     reserved2 : Pointer;       //Reserved; must be zero
     riid : PGUID;              //Specifies the GUID of the interface pointer
     out stgOpen :              //Address of an interface pointer
     IStorage ) : HResult; stdcall; external 'ole32.dll';
     ...
     implementation
     ...
     FileName:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
     res:=StgOpenStorageEx(PWideChar(FileName),
        STGM_READ or STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE,
        STGFMT_FILE,
        0, nil,  nil, @IID_IPropertySetStorage, stg);
     OleCheck(res);

     PropSetStg := Stg as IPropertySetStorage;

     open:=PropSetStg.Open(FmtID_SummaryInformation,
        STGFMT_FILE or STGM_READ or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, PropStg); //open=-2147287038 
     OleCheck(open); // EOleSysError "%1 could not be found
     ...
```

On instruction `OLECheck(Open)` I have an EOleSysError "%1 could not be found".
`Open` returns -2147287038

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong
[Article with full function code](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=992447)

IDE: Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3890.34076

Comment: 1) what is value of FileName ?
2) what is value of StgOpenStorageEx *before* OleCheck is called ?
3) do you import StgOpenStorageExA or StgOpenStorageExW ?

Comment: 1) FileName store filepeth to existing (100%) file. I need to get summary from this file

Comment: i don't like "%1" 
Please, DO show how you do declare FileName and how do you assign it value.
Also please DO add tag showing you delphi version. That might be important.
Discard the 3rd question about nameA or nameW - it seems be n/a to OLE

Comment: 1) FileName store filepeth to existing (100%) file. I need to get summary from this file. 2) returns 0 3) as I understand I imported just StgOpenStorageEx, maybe i am wrong...

Comment: Please do show exact sources where you do declare FileName and where you assign its value.  Please do edit your question and do add a tag showing exact Delphi version being used.

Comment: WinAPI.Windows.pas files has:
  { Success codes }
  S_OK    = $00000000;

MSDN claims: S_OK 
Indicates that the storage object was opened successfully.

Comment: The article that does not open here. Well, up to you.

Comment: 1) File exists near the application, so

fileName:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'testfile.doc';

2) Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3890.34076

Comment: As you can see in OleCheck sources, it can not through error on Zero parameter. You claim your StgOpenStorageEx returned S_OK value. That means it opened the file succesfuly. The error must be somewhere else, after the call. If you split it to ''var res: HResult; Res := StgOpen....; OleCheck(res);'' then none of statements alone should produce any error.

Comment: What is the data type of FileName?

Comment: I mean my post, not article by link. Please, do not be angry at me, it just language barrier

Comment: No, what data type if the variable FileName?

Comment: Read MSDN about STGFMT type.
STGFMT_FILE seems to be exactly what should NOT be called against DOC files

Comment: your advice helpful. Thank you. And can you tell me what the differense between this actions, why it not works without HRESULT variable?

Comment: your post does not have *declaration* of FileName variable. We may hope in Delphi XE it is string = UnicodeString. But you cold make it AnsiString or WideString or whatever any other string type. Also, there are tags below you article and Delphi-XE would better be specified in tags.

As of now i think you chosen wrong STGFMT constant. And you wrongly detect the soutce of error, either result value. Split calls to StgOpen and to OleCheck to different statements and trace then in different steps.

Comment: i can not, maybe some compilation error, or different OleCheck happened in the way. I do not.
If happened to me, i'd trace it in View / Debug/ CPU Window to check the difference in machine code. // i still think your error either was generated later, or result was not zero. And according to MSDN the chosen STFFMT constant is plainly wrong. Maybe you already modified file not realizing it, not it main content bu alternative content streams. Or whatever.

Comment: @Arioch No, I don't think that's right.

Comment: var FileName: widestring

Comment: OK, that's fine. Note that you'd be better with plain UTF-16 string on XE, but that's not the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what exactly ?

Comment: anyway, thank you. the main thing that it's all right

Comment: @alax_rosh WideString was used before Delphi 2009. Since then usual String (which is alias to UnicodeString) should be okay. Though WideString probably should work too here.

Comment: @arioch STGFMT_FILE is what you want for summary props

Comment: Is the file system NTFS?

Comment: try with brand new doc file, will it be okay or not.
i'd trust MSDN on that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380330.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "NTFS version 5.0 provides an implementation of IPropertySetStorage for files on an NTFS volume when the files themselves are not compound files" DOC is compound file or not ? That is like creating file.zip.zip If he want to wrap ANY file like txt or exe into external NTFS-based storage, than STGFMT_FILe is used. But if he want to look into EXISTING structure of ALREADY COMPOUND doc file - then there is STGFMT_DOCFILE for it.

Comment: Storing the HRESULT into local variable before calling OleCheck can't have fixed your problem. You changed something else. This therefore is a non-question.

Comment: @arioch ok, you are probably right

Comment: i would be definitely right if MS did not prohibited SGTFMT_ANY for StgOpenEx... Frankly, i just don';t know for now. I am just sure that topicstarter has Heisenbug and we did not discovered it :-(

Comment: You was right =( Similar code failed to. What means Heisenbug? )

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug   When it failed - did you checked the result manually ? and which exactly line failed ? did you tried another STGFMT value ? And look at the snippet i linked to. They use special preparation over filename.

Comment: the last code snippet has next to no info: 1) it does not show declaration (data type) of 'PropSetStg', 2) same for 'PropStg'; 3) it does not show data assigned to 'PropSetStg', 4) same for 'PropStg'; 5) it does not specify which line raises the exception, though we may try to guess; 6) it does not show the value of 'open'

As one thing to remember, *.DOC *.XLS *.MSC and some other files have properties inside them and are to be opened as FMT_STORAGE. Files like *.JPEG, *.TXT contain no properties, but 'may' be added with external linked properties, sometimes. Via FMT_FILE. Or not - no luck.

Comment: I added more details. Snippet that you're linked failed in the same place as my example

Comment: STG_E_FILENOTFOUND = 0x80030002
Did you tried FMT_DOCFILE and FMT_STORAGE instead ?
You may try SysInternals Process Explorer to look which files your application really tried to open (filtering by its exe name in filter and file i/o on toolbar) and cold not find. Perhaps those would be alternate NTFS data streams.

Comment: I used procmon. Application try to open an existing file, exactly the file, that I pass to function

Comment: Instead of what may i try FMT_DOCFILE and FMT_STORAGE? In which unit can I find FMT_DOCFILE and FMT_STORAGE? With uses list Windows, ComObj, ActiveX, Variants, Sysutils it is undeclared

Comment: Me and David discussed it last hour in this thread.
Again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380330.aspx - STGFMT_FILE is prohibited for DOC files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet uses STGFMT_ANY despite its prohibited status.
http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=115495

Maybe that is way to go, if it does work.
(that code used before-unicode Delphi. Usual checks and simplifications of upgrading to Unicode-aware Delphi would need to be applied)

That snippet makes use of *StringToOleStr* instead of typecast, and since even in Delphi XE2 that function is still more than typecast stub - it might make difference.

That snippet also differentiate between files having internal properties (like DOC, XLS, MSC files) and those that only 'maybe' are wrapped into external properties by NTFS-5 in Vista. STGFMT_* constants should be different for DOC and JPEG files for example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380330.aspx

Comment: @Alax_rosh: That tektips snippet came from me :). Arioch is spot on with the STGFMT_ANY remark. Just tested this on XE and it works... +1

Comment: Yeah!=) I got summary props from .doc. But it is just first step =( According to task, i need to get props from a lot of filetypes (.doc just most of them) Anyway, thanks a lot to you all

Comment: Well, that snippet asks the system is file has internal properties.
If it does not - it tries external ones.
Just that there is no warranty about their existence. Ur program should be ready for files without properties as well. ///

And while i don't know why SringToOle remains, unless someone would demonstrate that it is identical to typecast in all and every possible environment, i'd better use it. OLE to me is arcane language and if there is a function, i'd better use it, rather than have a slim chance to get arcane bug in some strange user environment, i'd be not able to reproduce.

Comment: @Arioch 'The, wouldn't be enough to say *use the proper flag according to file type* ? As an independent viewer I've read 34 comments to see what was wrong with the code from question. And sorry, from this answer I didn't get that...

Comment: Tried to get props from .tif (with properties), got fail. Trying to open file returns STG_E_FILENOTFOUND again. I can no longer think about it today, otherwise the my brain will explode ) In addition there is Independence day in my country today. Thanks to you all for help

Comment: @TLama No, it tells me nothing )

Comment: @TLama those comments you read now, after the question was modified few times. Without those comments you would be in David's shoes - composing answer, lecturing about casting from AnsiString to Unicode, only to delete it 10 minutes later.

"use the proper flag according to file type ?" was told in comment #15. And #17. And #18. If the advice was not followed then, don't ask me about that.

Comment: @Arioch, well, assume I'm somebody who came here after year having a StgOpenStorageEx problem. I just found this question and because of tl;dr effect I skipped the comments and went directly to the answer. First thing, the link to the forum is now over. So what should I do now ? How the OP fixed the problem year ago ? I'll say something wrong about StackOverflow and go to ask to my local forum. That's what can easily happen. I'm just saying - from your answer I didn't get how to fix that code (otherwise I might upvote).