# Delphi: How to SET(write) extended file properties?

Tags: windows, delphi, file-properties

I would like to set properties as shown in Windows Explorer File Properties->Summary Tab (Authors, Title, Subject, etc). (In Windows 7 is the Details tab)
I already know how to GET them using [StgCreateStorageEx](http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/File_Summary_Info.aspx),

The target file extensions are xls, xlsx, csv, txt and jpg files.
OS: Windows 2003/2008/XP/Windows 7.
Notice that this code will go a web service application and the server does not have Excel installed.

Note:It seems to be that there is no information/sample code about how to SET them. [image: Details tab]

Comment: If the answer address the question, happy to give it the thumbs up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: The set property Delphi code can be found [here](http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/File_Summary.aspx).
or if you have the latest JCL library - use TJclFilePropertySet at [jclNtfs.pas](http://upload.infosae.com.br/APLICATIVOS/Delphi%207%20Enterprise/Componentes_/Instalador/JEDI/jcl/source/windows/JclNTFS.pas)
Warning: Notice that this code works for xls files but it does not seem to work for txt/cvs and jpg files in Windows 7 Pro/Enterprise or 2008 (64 bits).
It seems that M$ has changed the way properties work in these OS: ["You can't add or change the file properties of some types of files. For example, you can't add any properties to TXT or RTF file"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-the-properties-for-a-file). Sadly for me, going back to XP mode is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

To write summary information use [IPropertyStorage:WriteMultiple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. See MSDN sample [WriteRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Not delphi but is easy to convert.

Answer (score 4):

```
function GetFileSummaryInfo(const FileName: WideString): String;

const
FmtID_SummaryInformation: TGUID =     '{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}';
FMTID_DocSummaryInformation : TGUID = '{D5CDD502-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}';
FMTID_UserDefinedProperties : TGUID = '{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}';
IID_IPropertySetStorage : TGUID =     '{0000013A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';

const
STGFMT_FILE = 3; //Indicates that the file must not be a compound file.
                 //This element is only valid when using the StgCreateStorageEx
                 //or StgOpenStorageEx functions to access the NTFS file system
                 //implementation of the IPropertySetStorage interface.
                 //Therefore, these functions return an error if the riid
                 //parameter does not specify the IPropertySetStorage interface,
                 //or if the specified file is not located on an NTFS file system
                 //volume.

STGFMT_ANY = 4; //Indicates that the system will determine the file type and
                //use the appropriate structured storage or property set
                //implementation.
                //This value cannot be used with the StgCreateStorageEx function.


// Summary Information
 PID_TITLE        = 2;
 PID_SUBJECT      = 3;
 PID_AUTHOR       = 4;
 PID_KEYWORDS     = 5;
 PID_COMMENTS     = 6;
 PID_TEMPLATE     = 7;
 PID_LASTAUTHOR   = 8;
 PID_REVNUMBER    = 9;
 PID_EDITTIME     = 10;
 PID_LASTPRINTED  = 11;
 PID_CREATE_DTM   = 12;
 PID_LASTSAVE_DTM = 13;
 PID_PAGECOUNT    = 14;
 PID_WORDCOUNT    = 15;
 PID_CHARCOUNT    = 16;
 PID_THUMBNAIL    = 17;
 PID_APPNAME      = 18;
 PID_SECURITY     = 19;

 // Document Summary Information
 PID_CATEGORY     = 2;
 PID_PRESFORMAT   = 3;
 PID_BYTECOUNT    = 4;
 PID_LINECOUNT    = 5;
 PID_PARCOUNT     = 6;
 PID_SLIDECOUNT   = 7;
 PID_NOTECOUNT    = 8;
 PID_HIDDENCOUNT  = 9;
 PID_MMCLIPCOUNT  = 10;
 PID_SCALE        = 11;
 PID_HEADINGPAIR  = 12;
 PID_DOCPARTS     = 13;
 PID_MANAGER      = 14;
 PID_COMPANY      = 15;
 PID_LINKSDIRTY   = 16;
 PID_CHARCOUNT2   = 17;

var
 I: Integer;
 PropSetStg: IPropertySetStorage;
 PropSpec: array of TPropSpec;
 PropStg: IPropertyStorage;
 PropVariant: array of TPropVariant;
 Rslt: HResult;
 S: String;
 Stg: IStorage;
 PropEnum: IEnumSTATPROPSTG;
 HR : HResult;
 PropStat: STATPROPSTG;
 k : integer;

function PropertyPIDToCaption(const ePID: Cardinal): string;
begin
 case ePID of
   PID_TITLE:
     Result := 'Title';
   PID_SUBJECT:
     Result := 'Subject';
   PID_AUTHOR:
     Result := 'Author';
   PID_KEYWORDS:
     Result := 'Keywords';
   PID_COMMENTS:
     Result := 'Comments';
   PID_TEMPLATE:
     Result := 'Template';
   PID_LASTAUTHOR:
     Result := 'Last Saved By';
   PID_REVNUMBER:
     Result := 'Revision Number';
   PID_EDITTIME:
     Result := 'Total Editing Time';
   PID_LASTPRINTED:
     Result := 'Last Printed';
   PID_CREATE_DTM:
     Result := 'Create Time/Date';
   PID_LASTSAVE_DTM:
     Result := 'Last Saved Time/Date';
   PID_PAGECOUNT:
     Result := 'Number of Pages';
   PID_WORDCOUNT:
     Result := 'Number of Words';
   PID_CHARCOUNT:
     Result := 'Number of Characters';
   PID_THUMBNAIL:
     Result := 'Thumbnail';
   PID_APPNAME:
     Result := 'Creating Application';
   PID_SECURITY:
     Result := 'Security';
   else
     Result := '$' + IntToHex(ePID, 8);
   end
end;

begin
 Result := '';
try
 OleCheck(StgOpenStorageEx(PWideChar(FileName),
 STGM_READ or STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE,
 STGFMT_FILE,
 0, nil,  nil, @IID_IPropertySetStorage, stg));

 PropSetStg := Stg as IPropertySetStorage;

 OleCheck(PropSetStg.Open(FmtID_SummaryInformation,
    STGM_READ or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, PropStg));

 OleCheck(PropStg.Enum(PropEnum));
 I := 0;

 hr := PropEnum.Next(1, PropStat, nil);
  while hr = S_OK do
  begin
    inc(I);
    SetLength(PropSpec,I);
    PropSpec[i-1].ulKind := PRSPEC_PROPID;
    PropSpec[i-1].propid := PropStat.propid;
    hr := PropEnum.Next(1, PropStat, nil);
 end;

 SetLength(PropVariant,i);
 Rslt := PropStg.ReadMultiple(i, @PropSpec[0], @PropVariant[0]);

 if Rslt =  S_FALSE then Exit;

 for k := 0 to i -1 do
  begin
    S := '';
    if PropVariant[k].vt = VT_LPSTR then
      if Assigned(PropVariant[k].pszVal) then
       S := PropVariant[k].pszVal;

    S := Format(PropertyPIDToCaption(PropSpec[k].Propid)+ ' %s',[s]);
   if S <> '' then Result := Result + S + #13;
 end;
 finally
 end;
```

for more http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/File_Summary_Info.aspx. Also this : http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1614 show you how to manipulate [[IPropertyStorage]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried some of the examples in Unicode Delphi ? I've tried the very same code [`from this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3051746/960757) in Delphi 2009 getting the `%1 not found` error at `PropSetStg.Open` like [`described here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12108295/960757).

Comment: @TLama - I have tried only in Delphi 7, on Windows XP some time ago, and it worked ok. This was the reason to post the code for this question. I did not knew about this problems. If is not working, OP can post a comment and I will delete the answer

Comment: @RBA, truth is that I haven't tried this with a non Unicode Delphi thinking about that *issue* as OS related (having Windows 7).

Comment: @RBA, the sample code is only how to get the properties(from the link), my question was regarding how to set the properties for the particular target files and OS

Comment: @RBA, My bad I forgot to mention the delphi central link in the question-did you use this code for server application or client desktop? Note: The second link uses ole objects but the target file is a word document.